# DON'T want blender to open the full size of my monitor on start up/opening a file

Tags: interface

I have a very large/wide monitor and every new instance of blender or reopening saved files it will open the program fullscreen/to the full extent of my monitor's display.
I prefer to work in a smaller window size as its just easier for me to comprehend. most programs you take them out of full screen and it remebers this on next start up, bender doesnt and it will continue to open maximised. is there a setting somewhere to have it always open windowed that im missing?

Answer (score 3):

Resize the window however you want, then go to `File` > `Defaults` > `Save startup file`

Comment: +1  I was just about to write the same ;) And best do it directly after starting up Blender. Or else other things you changed might be saved in the default as well.

Comment: Oh man this also remembers on which *monitor* the file opens ! Never noticed that.

Comment: @Gorgious Not just that it remembers any other settings, layout you change, if you add or remove new objects it will remember that too